# Access: Dynamically set Query criteria to Is Null or Is Not Null

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, isnull, dynamic-queries

First time posting a question, but I've been benifiting from some great advice here over the last few weeks while building my database, thanks all.

In Access I have a "search" form with multiple combo-boxes that a query references to generate a report that meets the varius search criteria. I have hit one problem however.

I want to be able to set the critera in one field of the query to *Is Null* or *Is Not Null* dependant on one of the comboboxes in my form.

eg: Combo box has two options "Home" and "Away". If "Home" is selected I want this to insert *Is Null* into the query criteria, and *Is Not Null* if it's "Away".

Currently I'm managing it in a rather clunky fashion with two separate queries, one for each option (but a separate button to launch the "search").

Solution would need to be Access 2007 compatible. I'm a relative beginner with VBA, learning by doing based on forum searches etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set your combo box to have two columns, hide the second column but bind to it. To do this, set the following properties:

- Column Count = 2
- Column Widths = 2cm; 0cm
- Bound Column = 2
- Row Source Type = Value List
- Row Source = Home; Is Null; Away; Is Not Null

Now your combo box shows **Home / Away** to the user, but returns **Is Null / Is Not Null** to the query.